# How can I display a grayscale raster in color in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, colors, tiff, raster

I have a .tif file of a landmass that denotes elevation. I want to display this raster with a color ramp as opposed to a grayscale ramp. How would I do this in Matlab?

I looked at the information associated with the tiff using:

```
[Z, R] = geotiffread('Landmass.tif')
```

which denotes the heading 'ColourType' as 'grayscale'. I tried to change this to 'winter' (one of matlabs in-built color schemes) but it made no difference.

At the moment I am using the following commands to display the tiff:

```
[Z, R] = geotiffread('Landmass.tif');
e=uint8(Z);
mapshow(e,R);
```

All the higher areas are white and everything else is black...even around the landmass (which I think I may have to cut/mask the landmass out to get rid of).
All the black colour is making it too difficult for me to display other shapefiles on top of the tiff, so I want to change the color scheme from grayscale to something lighter.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `colormap winter` is not working is because the output of `mapshow(e,R);` is RGB image format.
Even when the displayed image is gray, it is actually RGB, when r=g=b for each pixel.
I took Matlab `mapshow` example, converted `boston` image to Grayscale, and used `mapshow`.
For using `colormap winter`, I got image using `getimage`, convert it to Grayscale using `rgb2gray`, and then `colormap winter` worked when showing the image.

Check the following example:

```
[boston, R] = geotiffread('boston.tif');
boston = rgb2gray(boston); %Convert to Grayscale for testing.
figure
mapshow(boston, R);
axis image off

%Get image data, note: size of I is 2881x4481x3 (I is not in Grayscale format).
I = getimage(gca);

%Convert I from RGB (R=G=B) formtat to Grayscale foramt, note: size of J is
%2881x4481 (J is Grayscale format).

%%%%%%%Avoid image being rotated%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        %Close old image and open new figure
close Figure 1
    Figure
J = rgb2gray(I);

imshow(J);
colormap winter %Now it's working...
```

Boston with winter colormap:

[image]

Comment: @ Rotem That makes sense and your solution works perfectly. On a side note, after using the mapshow command and getting the gca for the image, I had to close the image before any of the other commands were executed. Otherwise, the display would be rotated. As I said though, once the original image was closed before it was redisplayed with the 'imshow(J)' command, nothing was rotated. Many thanks.

Comment: Sorry @Rotem..I thought I had accepted it. That's done now. I actually have a follow-on issue with this route. I can't map any shapefiles on top of the landmass.tif now, as technically, I'm not displaying it as a map anymore...so the spatial reference is lost. Do you know a way that I can alter the color scheme of the tiff and still treat it as a map? ie. display it using mapshow?

Comment: I think you need to do all the work on a map, and convert it to image on the final stage (before showing). It is also possible to use `mapshow(I, R);`, when I is already given with colormap.

Comment: hmm..I wonder then could I somehow specify 'I' with a colormap in ArcGIS. I might try that....It seems logical to me though that the 'Colourtype' characteristic of the raster should be modifiable in matlab. Also, I'm wondering if I plot my shapefiles on top of the raster and at the end try and modify the colour scheme as an image, will it alter the color scheme of everything collectively as an image...

Comment: Right... Look at [RGB = ind2rgb(X,map)](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2rgb.html) to see how to apply a colormap on grayscale image X. The syntax is: `RGB = ind2rgb(I, winter(256));` when I is in grayscale format.

Comment: @ Rotem Yes, that works to change to color format on the tiff and still maintains the spatial links (so shapefiles with the same projections can be overlaid). Unfortunately, every color scheme makes the non-land areas the darkest color. I'm looking for an equivalent of 'colormap(flipud(colormap))' to try and make the non land areas the lightest/brightest.

Comment: I remedied this by creating a custom colormap ranging from white to black and then incorporating it in my map:
xx=[0:0.01:1]'; 
xxx=flipud(xx);
yy=xxx; 
zz=xxx;
mapmap=horzcat(xxx,yy,zz);
RGB = ind2rgb(e2, mapmap);
mapshow(RGB,R);

Comment: Where e2 above is equivalent to what you referred to as 'I'

Comment: Yes `I` is equivalent to `e2`.  If you like, you can create reversed winter map as follows: `reversedWinterMap = flipud(winter(256));`